# MongoDB crashes 1 minute after launch on Ubuntu for Windows 10

Tags: windows, bash, mongodb, ubuntu

This issue is totally cryptic to me. Basically I'm just trying to launch a mongodb server installed in the Ubuntu environnement, and WiredTiger has issues after 1 minute.

Here is the ubuntu for windows system :

```
myname@DESKTOP-71PL1U2:/data$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
myname@DESKTOP-71PL1U2:/data$ uname -a
Linux DESKTOP-71PL1U2 3.4.0+ #1 PREEMPT Thu Aug 1 17:06:05 CST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I installed mongodb following the official instructions for the 14.04 ubuntu version. Then I'm just trying to launch it with `mongod`

After 1 minute (everytime), a big crash occurs and I have to delete the data/db folder and recreate it.

This is what it looks like

```
2016-09-17T19:19:01.298+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=4519 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=DESKTOP-71PL1U2
2016-09-17T19:19:01.299+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.9
2016-09-17T19:19:01.299+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 22ec9e93b40c85fc7cae7d56e7d6a02fd811088c
2016-09-17T19:19:01.300+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
2016-09-17T19:19:01.300+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-09-17T19:19:01.301+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-09-17T19:19:01.301+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-09-17T19:19:01.301+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1404
2016-09-17T19:19:01.301+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-09-17T19:19:01.302+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-09-17T19:19:01.302+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-09-17T19:19:01.319+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=4G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2016-09-17T19:19:01.387+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2016-09-17T19:19:01.387+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-09-17T19:19:01.388+0200 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
2016-09-17T19:19:01.388+0200 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2016-09-17T19:19:01.401+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2016-09-17T19:20:01.367+0200 E STORAGE  [thread1] WiredTiger (38) [1474132801:367500][4519:0x7f98b4f50700], file:index-1--1114464940503298809.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: /data/db/index-1--1114464940503298809.wt: handle-sync-nowait: sync_file_range: Function not implemented
2016-09-17T19:20:01.370+0200 E STORAGE  [thread1] WiredTiger (38) [1474132801:371063][4519:0x7f98b4f50700], checkpoint-server: checkpoint server error: Function not implemented
2016-09-17T19:20:01.371+0200 E STORAGE  [thread1] WiredTiger (-31804) [1474132801:371325][4519:0x7f98b4f50700], checkpoint-server: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
2016-09-17T19:20:01.374+0200 I -        [thread1] Fatal Assertion 28558
2016-09-17T19:20:01.374+0200 I -        [thread1]

***aborting after fassert() failure


2016-09-17T19:20:01.380+0200 F -        [thread1] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).

 0x13225f2 0x1321749 0x1321f52 0x7f98b8660330 0x7f98b82b6c37 0x7f98b82ba028 0x12a8662 0x10a28b3 0x1a88fcc 0x1a8944d 0x1a89834 0x1a0a7cb 0x7f98b8658184 0x7f98b837a37d
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"400000","o":"F225F2","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"400000","o":"F21749"},{"b":"400000","o":"F21F52"},{"b":"7F98B8650000","o":"10330"},{"b":"7F98B8280000","o":"36C37","s":"gsignal"},{"b":"7F98B8280000","o":"3A028","s":"abort"},{"b":"400000","o":"EA8662","s":"_ZN5mongo13fassertFailedEi"},{"b":"400000","o":"CA28B3"},{"b":"400000","o":"1688FCC","s":"__wt_eventv"},{"b":"400000","o":"168944D","s":"__wt_err"},{"b":"400000","o":"1689834","s":"__wt_panic"},{"b":"400000","o":"160A7CB"},{"b":"7F98B8650000","o":"8184"},{"b":"7F98B8280000","o":"FA37D","s":"clone"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.2.9", "gitVersion" : "22ec9e93b40c85fc7cae7d56e7d6a02fd811088c", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "3.4.0+", "version" : "#1 PREEMPT Thu Aug 1 17:06:05 CST 2013", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "elfType" : 2, "b" : "400000", "buildId" : "78E57AF736DDF3E8C558F60DB63F68BCF686D70A" }, { "b" : "7FFFFB0DD000", "elfType" : 3 }, { "b" : "7F98B95A0000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "74864DB9D5F69D39A67E4755012FB6573C469B3D" }, { "b" : "7F98B91C0000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "AAE7CFF8351B730830BDBCE0DCABBE06574B7144" }, { "b" : "7F98B8FB0000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E2A6DD5048A0A051FD61043BDB69D8CC68192AB7" }, { "b" : "7F98B8DA0000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DA9B8C234D0FE9FD8CAAC8970A7EC1B6C8F6623F" }, { "b" : "7F98B8A90000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D144258E614900B255A31F3FD2283A878670D5BC" }, { "b" : "7F98B8870000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "36311B4457710AE5578C4BF00791DED7359DBB92" }, { "b" : "7F98B8650000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "31E9F21AE8C10396171F1E13DA15780986FA696C" }, { "b" : "7F98B8280000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "CF699A15CAAE64F50311FC4655B86DC39A479789" }, { "b" : "7F98B9800000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D0F537904076D73F29E4A37341F8A449E2EF6CD0" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x32) [0x13225f2]
 mongod(+0xF21749) [0x1321749]
 mongod(+0xF21F52) [0x1321f52]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x10330) [0x7f98b8660330]
 libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37) [0x7f98b82b6c37]
 libc.so.6(abort+0x148) [0x7f98b82ba028]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo13fassertFailedEi+0x82) [0x12a8662]
 mongod(+0xCA28B3) [0x10a28b3]
 mongod(__wt_eventv+0x42C) [0x1a88fcc]
 mongod(__wt_err+0x8D) [0x1a8944d]
 mongod(__wt_panic+0x24) [0x1a89834]
 mongod(+0x160A7CB) [0x1a0a7cb]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x8184) [0x7f98b8658184]
 libc.so.6(clone+0x6D) [0x7f98b837a37d]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
2016-09-17T19:20:01.389+0200 I -        [TTLMonitor] Fatal Assertion 28559
```

I'll happily provide you any information necessary

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu-environment for Win10 is more considered as a proof of concept. Not really intended to be used a production environment for 'complex' tasks.

I suggest setting up a virtual machine with VMware or VirtualBox and save your sanity...

Comment: Well while I agree with you and surely don't intend to use it in production, I was hoping I could at least run a mongo local server. But as you imagine it's hard to know where the problem comes from. Though someone had the same problem as me, on a native ubuntu

Comment: I guess it's a missing dependency in a shared library or probably different behaviour than expected. Have you checked if there are any known bugs related to your problem description? I suggest to check that and then (if it's runnable under Win10) launch mongod through strace.

Comment: I gave up and installed via ```sudo-apt get install mongodb``` which is v2.4.9. It works despite multiple error messages, I can launch a server and use the dbs